# Python remove common substrings from two lists

Tags: python, list, substring

I have two lists: list_a and list_b. I want to remove not only the common strings in them, but also, the common (longest) substrings in them. The length of the lists could be different. For eg, some combinations of input are:

```
list_a = ['mens', 'room']
list_b = ['mensworld']
Expected output: 
list_a_out: ['room']
list_b_out: ['world']

list_a = ['flower']
list_b = ['mayflower', 'June']
Expected output:
list_a_out: []
list_b_out: ['may', 'June]

list_a = ['Chi', 'Construction']
list_b = ['Dex', 'Construction']
expected output:
list_a_out: ['Chi']
list_b_out: ['Dex']
```

So far, I have a developed a code that partially works:

def remove_common_substring_1(list_a, list_b):

```
final_list_a = []
final_list_b = []

flag_i_in_j = False
flag_j_in_i = False

for i in list_a:
    print("\n")
    for j in list_b:
        print(f'******* Processing {i, j} *******')
        if i in j:
            flag_i_in_j = True
            # remove i from j
            print(f'{i} is present {j}')
            print(f'Removing {i} from List A')
            final_list_a.append(list_a.remove(i))

            print(f'Removing substring {i} from {j} ')
            j_new = j.replace(i, '')
            final_list_b.append(j_new)

        elif j in i:
            flag_j_in_i = True
            print(f'{j} is present in {i}')
            print(f'Removing {j} from List B')
            final_list_b.append(list_b.remove(j))

            print(f'Removing substring {j} from {i}')
            i_new = i.replace(j, '')
            final_list_a.append(i_new)
        else:
            continue

    if not flag_i_in_j and not flag_j_in_i:
        final_list_a.append(i)
        #final_list_b.append(j)

final_list_a = list(filter(None, final_list_a))
final_list_b = list(filter(None, final_list_b))
return final_list_a, final_list_b
```

The above code works for one class of input:

```
list_a : ['mens', 'group']
list_b: ['cgkgroup']

output:
final_list_a: ['mens']
final_list_b: ['cgk']
```

I continuing to proceed step by and step and see if I can catch erroneous logic or see if I can do it in a completely different way. Any suggestions is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? In all of your examples the common substring happens to be a complete list entry in one of the list and in the other the substring is either at the beginning or the end. What if you have the lists `['stopping']` and `['top']`. Do you want the result to be `['sping']` and `[]`? What about `['abcsubstringdef']` and `['ghisubstringjkl']`? Do you want that to become `['abcdef']` and `['ghijkl']`?

Comment: I haven't thought about this scenario yet. Thanks for bringing this case up. I have to go back and explore my dataset to see if such cases would arise and if so, how they must be dealt, and what percentage (roughly) would have such cases.

Comment: Can you also describe what problem you're trying to solve with this? There might be a better approach overall.

Answer (score 1):

here is my attempt

```py
def removeCommon(list, s):
    result = []
    found = False

    for b in list:
        idx = b.find(s)

        if idx != -1:
            stripped = b[0:idx]+ b[idx + len(s):]
            if len(stripped) > 0:
                result.append(stripped)
            found = True
        else:
            result.append(b)

    return (found, result)
           

def remove_common_substring_1(list_a, list_b):
    list_a_out = []
    list_b_out = list(filter(lambda a: True, list_b))

    for a in list_a:
        found, list_b_out = removeCommon(list_b_out, a)
        if not found:
            list_a_out.append(a)

    return (list_a_out, list_b_out)        

print(remove_common_substring_1(['mens', 'room'], ['mensworld']))
print(remove_common_substring_1(['flower'], ['mayflower', 'June']))
print(remove_common_substring_1(['Chi', 'Construction'], ['Dex', 'Construction']))
```